# How to store argument?

Tags: python, scripting, arguments

The program will store the argument from the get_args() function, in order to use it in the main function. The get_args() function takes the arguments and prints it. I'm having trouble getting the argument to my main function.

```
import argparse

def get_args():
     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
     prog='Program Name goes here',
     description='What the program does goes here',
     epilog='Text at the bottom of help')
     parser.add_argument('password')          
     args = parser.parse_args()
input = (get_args)
     
  



def main():
     print(input)
 
if __name__ == '__main__' :
    main()
```

Comment: Don't use `input` as name, it's a built in function. Your function `get_args` should return `args`. You need to call `get_args`, i.e. add `()`. Move the line inside the `main()` function

Answer (score 1):

You can merge everything into single piece of code:

```
import argparse


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        prog='Program Name goes here',
        description='What the program does goes here',
        epilog='Text at the bottom of help')
    parser.add_argument('password')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args)
```